# How can I check out a file from another branch into a new file in the current branch with git?

Tags: git

Let's say that I have a file core.clj in branch master at HEAD which is distinct from core.clj in branch other at HEAD, and that I am currently in branch other.  I would like to checkout master's core.clj into the current branch with some other file name, say tmp.clj, for easy comparison.

How can I do this?

Comment: The question is not real. You are asking about some way to solve your problem, but what is the problem? What is the task you are solving?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `git show master:core.clj` to show the file. Redirect it to a new file (`git show ... > temp.clj` to save it for further processing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to; `git diff` will do exactly what you need to do.  `git diff master otherbranch core.clj` is a basic use of the command, and if you need more help, `man git-diff` can explain more to you.

Comment: Sure, the diff will usually suffice. But, let's say there was a formatting catastrophe that has rendered the diff unintelligible.  Is there a way to accomplish the task above?

Comment: @JamesAtwood other than manually copying the file out of the branch, not that I know of.  Someone else might come up with another answer that I didn't think of, though, so...

Comment: Understood.  Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

It is very straightforward:

```
 git checkout master -- core.clj
```

Comment: However, this doesn't save it to an alternate name, like the OP is hoping to do - instead, it overwrites your current file and essentially creates an unstaged change that will make the current branch's version of the file look like the version on `master`.

Comment: Hm, that's true, the question is vague. However, when you have the unstaged changes you could use standard tools to see the changes.

Comment: twalberg, just wanted to note that you are correct - I would like to save the file to an alternate name.